# Custom html.tpl.php and other templates for a module/specific content type. (DRUPAL 7)

Tags: drupal-7

Lets say I add this to my module:

```
function example_preprocess(&$vars,$node) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  'example__page_'.$node;    
}
```

Now every single item's theme gets overridden if I have a template.

However, the template files I've placed in the module don't work, they're only used if I put them in the **theme's template files**.

I'd like to **distribute a template with my module, and have it work in any theme**. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6) to designate the template files your module includes. See the [Using the theme layer (Drupal 6.x)](http://drupal.org/node/165706) handbook page for more details, under the *Registering theme hooks* and *Implementing default templates* sections.

Comment: I see, I'm going to try that now and report back.